# Cannot run 'dropIndexes' in a multi-document transaction

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Mongo for query from Database. And i try drop index by following code

```
mongoOperations.indexOps(MY_COLLECTION).dropIndex("rowIndex");
```

and i get error

```
Cannot run 'dropIndexes' in a multi-document transaction
```

How can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this, it happen because i place the code inside method with annotation @Transactional. Example:

```
@Transactional
void funnyAction(){
    mongoOperations.indexOps(MY_COLLECTION).dropIndex("rowIndex");
}
```

I have fixd by moving the code outside the method